# java.nio.SocketChannel always returning the same data

Tags: java, sockets, nio

could you please have a look at my code :

```
    private void initSocket() {
        try {
            socketChannel = SocketChannel.open();
            socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
            socketChannel.bind(null);
            socketChannel.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host,port));
            while(! socketChannel.finishConnect() ){
                Thread.sleep(5);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void initOutput() {
        outBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(512);     //Allocate direct for better performance (no java-heap alloc)
        outBuffer.clear();
    }

    private void initInput() {
        inBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1024);     //Allocate direct for better performance (no java-heap alloc)
        inBuffer.clear();
    }

    public String in () {
        try {
            while (socketChannel.re)
            socketChannel.read(inBuffer);
            inBuffer.mark();
            final String ret = Charset.forName("UTF-8").newDecoder().decode(inBuffer).toString();

            bulletin.PIPE_IN.Info.push(" <<< ", new String[]{"TsPipe2","in"}, new Object[]{ret, inBuffer});

            return ret;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        return null;
    }

    public void out (String out) {
        outBuffer.clear();
        outBuffer.put(out.getBytes());

        //Write all in one go

        bulletin.PIPE_OUT.Info.push(" >>> ", new String[]{"TsPipe2","out"}, new Object[]{outBuffer, out});

        int toWrite = outBuffer.remaining();

        for (int i = 0; i < toWrite; ++i) {
            try {
                i += socketChannel.write(outBuffer);
                Thread.sleep(Period.NIO_CHANNEL_WRITE_SLEEP.getValue());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And tell me what am I doing wrong ?

As the topic states I am always getting the same data from the in-method and am not sure wether my out-method works or not

I travelled throught several tutorials now and it might be I mixed something up.
I also found promising stuff on stackoverflow - but nothing ever worked.

As a little background info - I am writing a Teamspeak bot communicatin via Sockets with a TS-Server and have gone pretty far. From the moment I first heard about nio I wanted to migrate to it.

Are their other frameworks to consider ? heard Google Grizzly is pretty neat, but not sure if it's useful for my case ?

Comment: Where are you clearing the buffer?  I suggest you change your code to handle partial reads and multiple messages at once.  TCP is a stream protocol, not a messaging protocol.

Comment: You are doing almost everything wrong. (1) `read()` returns a value which you are ignoring. (2) The sleeps are literally a waste of time. (3) ` while (socketChannel.re)` doesn't compile. (4) `inBuffer.mark()` is pointless here, as you aren't calling `reset()`. (5) You aren't calling `inBuffer.compact()` or 'inBuffer.clear()`, before reading, so reads will fill it up pretty quickly and start returning zero. You need to look at a good tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're missing some braces at this `while (socketChannel.re)` loop.

Comment: Missing a whole lot of code there, evidently.